# WebApi - PostAsync

Tags: asp.net-web-api, async-await

Im having trouble with this, I dont why, it must be something im doing wrong. I've had to rewrite to get it working but it smells all wrong, however it works.

So this is what I tried first and it does not work, as the statuscode of 500 was returned, but this is because it was not waiting for a response, I need it to wait

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Booking(string model)
{
    //do some bits.
    var a = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e);
    var booking = new HttpClient();
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(a,Encoding.UTF8);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await booking.PostAsync("https://webapi.domain.com/Booking/Post", content);
    var aa = response.StatusCode //500 Internal Error
}
```

So I rewrote

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> Booking(string model)
{
    //do some bits.
    var a = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(e);
    var booking = new HttpClient();
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(a,Encoding.UTF8);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await booking.PostAsync("https://webapi.domain.com/Booking/Post", content);
    var t = new Stopwatch();

    while (response.StatusCode ==HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        t.Start();
        var zzzz = response.ReasonPhrase;
        if (t.ElapsedMilliseconds >10000)
        {
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout;
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
    var aa = response.StatusCode //201 Created
}
```

And this works and returns me my 201, ugly, but can anyone tell me and show me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please format the code!

Comment: what is `booking.PostAsync` ? Why don't you directly go there ?

Comment: I find it really unlikely that the second piece of code works when the first one does not. Are you sure? The response status code does not change after some time. The HTTP protocol has no way to "update" a response that was sent. All this timing stuff does nothing.

Comment: A status code of 500 generally means something went wrong on the server, in .net (*example: web service or web api*) this usually indicates an un-handled  Exception occurred. Your first example (provided code) looks technically fine and should work. You should debug the end point `webapi.domain.com/Booking/Post` to figure out what is going wrong (unexpected passed in data, data not in correct format, data missing, network issue, who knows). Your "work around" (code part 2) does not fix the problem.

Comment: i have not changed the end point, running through the code a 201 is returned., its as if the await does not actually wait, if I use the second part of the code it works no problem and a 201 is sent back

Comment: This is highly unlikely. Start Fiddler and set it as a proxy in web.config (this is easy). Make sure that Fiddler agrees with your assessment of the response codes. Then, find out the difference in the requests you are sending. I'd bet money there is a difference, or your interpretation of the responses is wrong.

Comment: For more help you should also post what you have in `//do some bits.` At this point its a guessing game as to why your code that really should not work is some how working for you. And follow the recommendation on debugging by @usr with Fiddler, as was already mentioned a response status code will not change by itself after it has been received.

Comment: fiddler shows this "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending."

Comment: That's 5xx I take it? So it's not 201.

Comment: yeap, thats why when i step through the code a 201 is sent back

Comment: I did not understand that sentence. You found 5xx with Fiddler so your code should perceive a 5xx as well, right?

Comment: So if i take off all break points, 500 is returned with "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending".  however if I step through the code on the end point (ie https://webapi.domain.com/Booking/Post) a 201 is sent back

Answer (score 1):

The server has a timing dependent bug. It goes away when you use the debugger to give it enough time to avoid the crash.

> An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

Looks like something with async.

The client is not at fault and the `while (response.StatusCode ==HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)` loop does nothing. It does not even change the timing at the server. Your usage of the debugger probably did that and the two effect were confounded in your interpretation.

Fix the server, now that you know where to look.

Comment: Hi, Ive narrowed it down to the sending of an email (the email actually sends, no error is thrown in debug)  public bool SendMail(string from, string to, string subject, string body, bool html)
        {...} any ideas?

Comment: Well, strictly speaking the question is solved because the client side problem is solved (it does not exist). The best course of action would be to ask a question with details about the server crash. But it looks like you are starting some async action and not waiting for completion. That's what the message says. So audit the code for such a thing. Anything with "async" in its name is interesting.